# Load svg as path

Tags: html, css, sass, webpack

I use webpack via CLI, like `webpack --watch`.
Goal is to compile JS with SASS and put in some separate html page.

I have some links to svg files in my sass, looking like that:

```
label {
    background: url(../images/checkbox.svg);
    }
```

The problem is that I never get it in the browser after compiling. I have following situations:

1. If I compile it using svg-loader, in browser I see compiled css is something like that:
   `background: url([object Object]);`

[Here is suggested](https://github.com/bhovhannes/svg-url-loader/issues/1) to use `svg-url-loader` instead.

2. If I use mentioned `svg-url-loader`, I have whole page css messed up which makes browser to show raw text instead of styled page.
3. If I use `file-loader`, I get css compiled to background:

`background: url(37efc0ccedf6fe109636ad1416c29425.svg)`

and as I put resulted bundle.js to some other place, I am not happy with copying some files I already have.

4. If I use `raw-loader`, I get some xml instead of file name in the url(...), which just doesn't work, showing "wrong property value" error in the css.
   I would be happy to get just regular path instead of all that things, like

`background: url(../images/checkbox.svg);`

So what is correct approach to handle svg in my situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```
    {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file?name=/resources/[path][name].[ext]'
    },
    {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'file?name=/resources/[path][name].[ext]'
    }
```

This way loader preserves name and path and prepends additional `/resources/`folder.